# Issue with installing theme via Admin Dashboard (.htaccess issue)

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting "Access denied. You are not authorized to access this page." 
at "/admin/appearance/install?token=..." (Only this page alone) while trying to install a custom theme.

I am quiet certain that it's due to the configuration in .htaccess. Unable to read the token query parameter.
I need help editing the .htaccess rewrite rule for installing new theme.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In a plain Drupal installation, the .htaccess file doesn't have rewrite rules for that page. Are you sure you have the permission to install new themes?

Comment: Thank you.
I am logging in as administrator, have permission to install new themes and currently using apigee kickstart theme. And trying to upload a new theme based on the apigee kickstart theme.
It seems like Drupal or apache is not recognizing the query parameters. I am getting access denied on /install?token and /default?token pages.

Comment: Update : The issue is solved by switching back the admin theme to the default one instead of a custom one (In my case is the Apigee custom theme provided by Apigee kickstart).